# C++  function using reference as param error

Tags: c++

```
struct node {

  string info;
  node *next;

  node() {
   info = "string";
   next = NULL;

  }

};

void insert(node &anode) {
 node newNode;
 anode.next = &newNode;
}
```

What is wrong with this implementation of insert for this structure ? How should I fix this?
**added:** Very sorry that I wasn't clear. I know what is wrong with the program. I want to know how I can insert a new node to a reference node. Since I am using a reference to a node as a param this mean that node must not be a pointer? So its stored on stack? which means I can't use memory from heap? (or else seg fault?) so how am I suppose to use new ? This is my main confusion. Perhaps my approach is wrong but I don't see why it should be.

Comment: Why do you believe something is wrong?  Do you get a compile error?  a runtime error?  Or does your homework state that there is a problem, and ask you to explain?

Comment: Nothing as far as I can see - what error are you getting? Your question implies an error when calling insert - perhaps you should show us the calling code.

Comment: Its not homework I am trying to implement a structure for a program while learning c++. Perhaps my wording is bad (ps my computer is very slow on stackoverflow).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's wrong is that `newNode` lives in the scope of the `insert` function. You probably want something like

```
void insert(node &anode) {
 node* newNode = new node;
 anode.next = newNode;
}
```

but the parent node, or something else, then has to take care of the new node's lifetime. It now owns the `next` node. If you want the caller to be in charge, then this might be more suitable:

```
void insert(node& parentNode, node& nextNode) {
 parentNode.next = &nextNode;
}
```

Note that you can avoid some of the lifetime issues by using [boost::shared_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) or `std::shared_ptr` if you have access to C++0x. These smart pointers basically wrap a pointer and take care to delete it when nobody is using it. The code would look something like this:

```
struct node {
  // other data members...

  shared_ptr<node> next;

  // constructors/destructors 
};

void insert(node& anode) {
  anode.next = shared_ptr<node>(new node);
}
```

Now you don't have to worry about deleting the new node at any point.

Comment: I am getting can not convert node** to node* in assignment for the first one.

Comment: @Mark, I had a typo in the first example: anode.next = newNode; NOT anode.next = &newNode

Comment: For the second one does it work if I use it inside a function? Also my when I ran my program I didn't declare anode as a pointer, which means its placed on stack. This gave me a seg error, do you know why? I am going to try pointer to see if no error is coming.

Comment: Yes and no. What really matters is the lifetime of nextNode. If you just create it in the function as a local, then you have the same problem as in your original post. If it is newed, then something has to take care of deleting it at the right moment. Maybe you can explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: For the second, i think that the `nextNode` parameter must be a non-const reference (since the `next` pointer is non-const too ...)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. You see I am trying to implement a structure--and more specifically a tree node and I would like to reuse to data for many other function and a reference seem to be the right approach. But so far its tricky to do it without ever used C++ before.

Comment: @MartinStettner You're right, I've fixed this. Another option would be for the `node*` member to be const, but I'm not sure if that would break OP's design.

Comment: @Mark Your node only has one `next`, so it looks like a linked list node. This adds some complexity: when you insert a node, what happens if the parent was pointing to another node? You need some clearly defined action here. For a tree, you'd have many children nodes per parent, so you can just add nodes without too much worry.

Comment: @Mark, also note that if a node is part of a tree, you cannot really re-use it in another tree, since it holds a pointer to it's next node. You probably care about the value attached to the node (a string in this example), rather than the node itself. It may be worth hiding the details of nodes and node manipulations in a tree class, to which you can add objects (strings or whatever it is you want to store). This is in line with the approach taken by C++ standard library containers.

Answer (score 2):

You're returning (implicitly, as member of `anode`) a pointer to the local variable `newNode`. `newNode` is destroyed when you're leaving `insert`, so `anode.next` contains an invalid pointer afterwards.

BTW: should this question be tagged "homework"? :)

Answer (score 1):

The "what's wrong" has nothing to do with references.

This implementation stores a pointer to a local variable in `anode.next`. Local variable gets destroyed immediately afterwards (when `insert` function exists), while the pointer continues to live pointing into a destroyed location.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the local variable `newNode` will go out of scope once the function `insert` exists, and `anode.next` will now reference an invalid node.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are talking about a *runtime* error. The problem is that in your `insert` function

```
node newNode
```

is only a local variable, and it will be causing a problem when you try to access it later while iterating on the node(s).

Inside the insert function you should be doing something like this:

```
node* newNode = new node();
anode.next = newNode;
```

Comment: I just changed it a bit, can you see if you are using the latest code in my answer.

Comment: It would still give seg fault error... Since anode is on stack and newNode is on heap.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on using free functions, your best bet is probably something like:

```
static node* head = NULL;
static node* current = NULL;

void insert(std::string& val)
{
    if (!head) {
       current = new node(val);
       head = current;
    } else {
       current->next = new node(val);
       current = current->next;
    }
}
```

and having your constructor accept an std::string as an argument. Relying on an entity outside the function to create nodes for you is probably not the best idea. You can pseudo-encapsulate that by creating nodes on demand when you call insert. Then you can run through the nodes using the head pointer and consequently delete them when you're finished with the list.

Comment: Just changed the code around in the if statement... had the assignments reversed.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a static address.

```
void insert(node &anode) {
 node newNode;
 anode.next = &newNode;
}
```

newNode is a local object. At the end of the function, it will go out of scope and its address will be invalid.